# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in VB.net with Access 2013

Tags: vb.net, criteria

```
If ssearch.Text <> "" Then
        cmdOLEDB.CommandText = "SELECT StudentID FROM Students WHERE StudentID = " & (ssearch.Text) & " ; "
        cmdOLEDB.Connection = cnnOLEDB
```

I have tried many solution but none of them helped. Either they pop out a no value etc etc and this error. I'm trying to search `Student ID` from my access and display it out. Is there an error in the above part. `ssearch.text` is the `textbox` in which I type the number I want to search.

Answer (score 0):

The Datatype for `StudentID` in the data base is may not be an integer. but you are passing this field in where condition as an integer. in queries,

String or character is represented within a pair of single quotes(`' '`). so your query will be like the  following:

```
   cmdOLEDB.CommandText = "SELECT StudentID FROM Students WHERE StudentID = '" & (ssearch.Text) & "';"
```

but the best way is to use [`parameterized`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) queries, instead for this  to avoid [`sql injection`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).